# Нужно ли обособлять деепричастный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

***Если**(,) решая задачу(,) / знать отвЕт, // **то это неинтерЕсно.***

***СПП*** со **взаимообусловленными** отношениями.

Нужно ли **обособлять** деепричастный оборот? Предложение нераспространенное, будет много запятых.

Можно ли считать, что оборот не обозначает **действие**, а имеет **обстоятельственное** значение (= при решении задачи)? Тогда оборот не обособляется.

Comment: Вопрос хороший, плюс я уже поставил. Но мне кажется, лучше обособить. :)

Comment: Спасибо, Максим,  а почему? У нас много ориентиров: грамматика, семантика, интонация, графика. Вы можете привести примеры таких конструкций из литературы?  Вот даже графика: с запятой непривычно, без обособления – тоже.

Comment: Почему? Да просто. Я просто считаю, что нужно обособить. Это лишь моë мнение.

Comment: Интуиция? Вижу деепричастный оборот и обособляю? Чем отличается "решая" и "при решении"?

Answer (score 0):

Его можно не обособить, только если что-то сравнивая (и тогда будет то самое ударение), например:

> Что если делая, будет интересно?

> Если решая задАчу знать отвЕт, то это неинтерЕсно.

В вашем случае — обособление. Интонация — подтверждение.

`Если, решая задачу, знать отвЕт, то это неинтерЕсно.`

(Можно даже деепричастный оборот здесь как бы опустить, т. к. смысл — это известность ответа, мэм.)

Comment: Всё это косвенные догадки, которые формируют интуитивное решение. А интонация здесь такая: Если решая задачу/ знать отвЕт, // то это неинтерЕсно. После "если" паузы нет никакой, после "задачу" произносительная  пауза. Точно такая интонация в этом предложении: Если при решении задачи/ знать отвЕт, // то это неинтерЕсно.   А обособления нет. Почему? Мне тоже думается, что оборот надо обособить, но для этого нужны точные доказательства.  А они, вероятно есть... Так какие же?

Answer (score 0):

1. При решении задачи надо **сравнить варианты:**

(1) *Если(?) **решая задачу**(,) / знать отвЕт, // то это неинтерЕсно.*

(2) *Если **при решении задачи** / знать отвЕт, // то это неинтерЕсно.*

2. Интонация и смысл **одинаковые,** а пунктуация **разная**, а почему?
3. В одном случае названо **само действие** (решая), а в другом случае (при решении) есть только **название действия**. Может, в этом разница?
4. **Да, пожалуй.** Деепричастные обороты — это обстоятельства различного вида. У нас обстоятельство **времени**, значение одновременного **действия** для глагола и деепричастия.  А необособленный вариант возможен только для оборотов со значением **образа действия.**
5. Поэтому оборот  нужно обособить: *Если, **решая задачу**, знать ответ, то это неинтересно.*

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

Различные **виды обстоятельств**, выраженных деепричастиями и деепричастными оборотами

(1) Обстоятельство **времени (одновременные действия)**

Ощупывая ногами дно, Григорий по пояс окунулся в воду.
Держа кувшин над головой, грузинка узкою тропой спускалась к берегу.

(2) Обстоятельство **времени (последовательные действия)**

Оставив немного сухарей, старик ушёл.
Даже овладев собой, он долго не мог отделаться от странности такого совпадения.
Князь Андрей, сделав распоряжения об отъезде, ушёл в свою комнату.

(3) Обстоятельство **образа действия**

Онегин, взорами сверкая, из-за стола, гремя, встаёт.
Звёзды, мерцая, ниже и ниже опускались над землёй.

(4) Обстоятельство **причины**

Собака, не желая выдавать своего страха, залаяла и бросилась к коту.
Она несколько успокоилась, увидев, что ветер ослабел.

(5) Обстоятельство **цели**

Я глядел во все стороны, ожидая увидеть грозные бастионы.
На красных лапках гусь тяжёлый, задумав плыть по лону вод, ступает бережно на лёд.

(6) Обстоятельство **условия**

Сидя дома, мир не посмотришь.
Никогда не берись за последующее, не усвоив предыдущего.

(7) Обстоятельство **сопоставления**

Стараясь запомнить детали, он часто упускал из вида самое важное.